# Sending functions to fold in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I send an accumulation function to fold in Scala, the below example will say `(Int,Int,Int) does not take parameters`.

My questions are:

- Why do I get this error?
- How is the idomatic way to do what I want in the code below?

  ```
  def a(xs: List[(Int,Int)]): Int = {

  def logic(acc: (Int,Int, Int), post: (Int,Int)): (Int,Int,Int) = {
      // do some logic

      (1, 2, 3)
  }

  val to = xs foldLeft((0,0,0))(logic _)

  to._3
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
xs foldLeft((0,0,0))(logic _)
```

Never go for the dotless notation unless it's for an operator. This way it works.

```
xs.foldLeft((0,0,0))(logic _)
```

Without a context I believe this is idiomatic enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the goal of your code but the problem you described can be solved this way:

```
val to = xs.foldLeft((0,0,0))(logic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
xs.foldLeft((0,0,0), logic)
```

Answer (score 1):

`foldLeft` is a curried function so it requires a `.` - go for `xs.foldLeft` and it will work.

Comment: Downvote without an explanation does not benefit anyone.